# DateTime want just AM/PM portion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, object

I do have a column that looks like this:

```
Time        Qty_sold
12:00 pm    2 
12:01 pm    5
12:05 pm    4
05:07 am    2
06:09 am    1
```

The time column is an object and i will like to just retrieve the am/pm portion. How will i be able to do that? I did try the code below to slide my data, and it didnt work.

```
df_sales_sum['am/pm'] = df_sales_sum['Time'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(np.int64)
```

Are there any other ways to just get the AM/PM part?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "the time column is an object", do you mean a string?

Comment: Hi @jarmod, no the dtype is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. you need `.str[-2:]`

Use:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['12:00 pm', '12:01 pm', '12:05 pm', '05:07 am', '06:09 am']})
df["'am/pm'"] = df['Time'].str[-2:]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Time am/pm
0  12:00 pm    pm
1  12:01 pm    pm
2  12:05 pm    pm
3  05:07 am    am
4  06:09 am    am
```